# how to get map api release key with intellij idea?

Tags: android, api, dictionary, android-keystore

Edit:

1. At this point I should be ensured that if I can create it succesfully, does it run on an apk which downloaded outside google market? I mean will it run correctly if I publish the app via my server? 
   **YES**
2. There are a few examples related to getting "release key" but nothing could help me. I generated my debug key and it worked without any problem. But I could not reach to get release api key. I did almost everything written on internet and stackoverflow.

What should I do to get release key if I have debug key?

**ANSWER**: http://chocotech.blogspot.com/2012/10/get-debug-key-and-release-key-for.html

Comment: http://chocotech.blogspot.com/2012/10/get-debug-key-and-release-key-for.html